# How do I access my Player Camera Manager (replicated (listen server and client)) in UE4 Blueprints

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, session-replication

When I try to access the location of my Player Camera Manager on the server it returns 0, 0, 0.

I think that I tried every option on setting the Player Camera Manager respectively the Player Controller in all the replicated options. To be clear: At first, I used my common sense but after a week of failure I tried every combination with no success.

As an example: Here is how I tried to access the Location and the forward Vector for a Line Trace
[image: As an example: Here is how I tried to access the Location and the forward Vector for a Line Trace]

I also tried to set the Camera Manager as a variable (I tried both server and client) and then access it on the server.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix that?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`APlayerCameraManager` is not an actor that replicates, so I'd expect that blueprints to only work on the client. You'll have to replicate the values you need back to the server.

If you're making a first person game `APawn` replicates a variable named `RemoteViewPitch` that may be enough depending on what you're doing.

Comment: So I should receive my PlayerCameraManager on the client and use this value to replicate it to the server in a separate Event?

Comment: I made it like this: https://blueprintue.com/blueprint/d1i9lu0t/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just make an interface function with input the information that you need from the manager then go to character and assign that to it then go to the manager blueprint and get the information and use controlled pawn to get ur player ref and call interface function

Comment: Could you provide an example please

Answer (score 0):

[image: Blueprint Interface]
[image: BP_ThirdPersonCharacter]
[image]

You need to create a blueprint interface, and create a function to get camera values, then on your character implement that interface and add the camera values from the player camera, then on your other BP just get those values.